# exec.command for patch command

Tags: go, patch, goland

I am trying to patch a file using the below command

```
patch -p0 < <file_path>
```

My runCommand syntax is as below:

```
func runCommand(cmd string, args ...string) error {
    ecmd := exec.Command(cmd, args...)
    ecmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    ecmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    ecmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    err := ecmd.Run()
    return err
}
```

Now I am passing my patch command as below:

```
cmd = "patch"
args := []string{"-p0", "<",  "/tmp/file"}
err = runCommand(cmd, args...)
```

But I am seeing the below error:

**patch: **** Can't find file '<' : No such file or directory**

Can you please let me know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing this paragraph from the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/):

> Unlike the "system" library call from C and other languages, the
>   os/exec package intentionally does not invoke the system shell and
>   does not expand any glob patterns or handle other expansions,
>   pipelines, or redirections typically done by shells. The package
>   behaves more like C's "exec" family of functions. To expand glob
>   patterns, either call the shell directly, taking care to escape any
>   dangerous input, or use the path/filepath package's Glob function. To
>   expand environment variables, use package os's ExpandEnv.

The shell is responsible for handling `<` operations. You can set `stdin` yourself with the file as input or you can use the shell. To use the shell, try something like:

```
runCommand("/bin/sh", "patch -p0 < /tmp/file")
```

Note that this won't work on Windows. Reading the file and writing to `stdin` yourself is a more easily portable solution.